# Show button after time (handler?)

Tags: java, android, button, count, handler

I'm developing a little app, the idea is that the user clicks a buton in 15 seconds, there's textview which counts how many clicks he does. Now I want to add a restart button, but I want to show it after 15 seconds. Do you guys have any idea how to do that? Here's my code:

```
  final TextView textic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Typeface fac=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/fipps.otf");
    textic.setTypeface(fac);
        final int oldscore = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("highscore", 0);


        count = new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) { // MOVED UP
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                int seconds = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000));
                textic.setText("Time Left: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                String message;
                textic.setText("Time's Up!");
                buttonCount.setEnabled(false);
                if (clicks > oldscore) {
                    getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("highscore", clicks).commit();

                }
            }
        };
        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clicks);
    Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/fipps.otf");
    textView.setTypeface(face);
    buttonCount = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                clicks++;
                textView.setText("" + clicks);
                TextView textVie = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.topScoreView);
                Typeface fa=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/fipps.otf");
                textVie.setTypeface(fa);
                textVie.setText("Best: " + oldscore);

                if(!started){
                    count.start(); // START COUNTDOWN TIMER
                    started = true;
                    timerProcessing = true;

                }

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Could someone please help me, what should I do?

Comment: you hide the button by setting the visibility and later after 15 seconds make it visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the button in your layout like your textview and set it unvisible.Set it visible when time's out(in onfinish()).

Answer (score 0):

This is my code. I used this to hide a layout after 5 seconds,, use this. Hope this will help u

```
private void HideLayout()
{
    swiper=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.llSwiper);
    header=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llHeader);
    swiper.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            if(!swiper.isPressed())
            {
                swiper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                HideLayout();
            }
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Use your buttons instead of the layout